# userSettings not loaded from .config unless in startup project?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, settings

I've got a solution with a project layout of:

- View (Startup project, `app.config`)
- Settings (`ApplicationSettings.Settings`, `app.config`)

There in an `ApplicationSettings.Settings` file inside of the settings project which contains various user settings. This project also has an `App.config` file. This config file is mostly empty.

Now it's my understanding that the userSettings will load from the startup project config file in the output folder. Aka `View.exe.config`. This file (and the View `app.config`) contains my wanted startup user settings.

However after trying to get this working I can only get the `View.exe.config` changes to be loaded if the `ApplicationSettings.Settings` file is placed in the View project. And in no scenario is anything loaded from the Settings `App.Config`.

I'm aware these files are replaced when you rebuild and debug and that's not the issue. I also know that when you save the values are saved into your appData folder and there is nothing saved in there at this time.

Basically my question is can you have a settings file outside of the startup project which loads from a .config file when you run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do following things here.

1. Make sure that settings file get copied from other project to startup project when project builds. You can achieve this by using post build script.
2. Write config section or handler to read settings value from the settings file.
3. Configure config section handler in app.config and add config section with config source path pointing to relative path to the settings file in startup project.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at the config sections and realised that visual studio had generated them with the wrong name. Was generating them with `Settings.Properties.Settings` when it should of been `Settings.ApplicationSettings`